# How can I troubleshoot connection failures from the emulator?

Tags: java, android, networking, android-emulator, httpclient

I am trying to connect with the emulator with a server having a hostname set.
The actual IP is an internal IP and I am connected via WIFI to the network.
I can access the IP from the browser just fine but with the Emulator I either get:

> java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host
>   “internal.server.com”: No address associated with hostname    at
>   java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:427)

And a couple of times I got a Connection refused for some reason.

> Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed:
>   ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

I have tried adding a proxy in the Emulator settings in case it was a routing issue, removing the proxy but it is not possible to connect.
How can I debug this?

The way I try to connect is:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = null;
response = client.execute(httpGet);
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
etc
```

In my manifest I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

How can I troubleshoot connection failures from the emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to try from the emulator 2-3 times in a row. It seems it needs a couple of mins for the emulator to be in sync with WIFI or something like that.